# Android set ringtone and notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, ringtone

Hi I have a problem saving sound as ringtone or notification.
I keep getting my set Toast - Failed - Check your SDCard

Where is the mistake?

Code: http://pastebin.com/in5ckvk0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
  String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/sdcard/media/ringtone/";
```

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`  would anyways return you the /SDCard path, use some other folder name to store the Ringtone. like /yourPackage/media instead of /sdcard/media

as it would be then interpreted as `/SDCard/yourPackage/media/`

hope it helps

Comment: yes, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` would anyways return you the /SDCard path so skip that part instead

Comment: Use `String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/yourPackage/com.ring/media"‌​;`

Comment: Now i have errors:
(481): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
(481): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
(481):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:816)
AndroidRuntime(481):  at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:798)

 InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);

(savering(selectedSoundId)){   

 if(item.getTitle()=="Ringtone"){function1(item.getItemId());}

Comment: dont use the Default Android package name and try testing it with your own package/folder name, it might be possible that the Folder you are currently writing to isn't accessible, rather create your own folder and try again.

Comment: String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.ring/‌​media"; 
Doesn't work...

Comment: check in the emulator for the path `/sdcard` has it created the folder `com.ring/` I am starting to doubt that is it a read operation that is causing the exception on the Raw file reading of the media file

Comment: Do let me know which line the exception is caused after debugging your code

Comment: If I run on the phone with the sdcard is also not working.

How do I add it automatically chose the recording on SD or internal memory?

Comment: Debug when i clicked " set Ringtone"
http://pastebin.com/Xx7Z9SQT
Stood on it and is stuck

Comment: You aren't experiencing an Exception due to Storing on SDCard, its because you aren't able to open the Raw Resource folder to read your Music files from within it. Have you placed your Ringtones(media files with .ogg) in the res/raw folder of your project?

Comment: In your `getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);` try placing a static file as `ressound=R.raw.yourFile.ogg` just to test.

Comment: you Tried ressound=R.raw.yourFile right, not with the Extension, it was a typo, what exception did it give this time when you made everything Static?

Comment: is it unsubscribed SDCard?, Is your emulator defined with an SDCard during its creation?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sm2g1ije <-- Erros if i have:

 209 line: InputStream fIn =getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(ressound);
128 line:          (savenot(selectedSoundId)){   
107 line:       else if(item.getTitle()=="Notification"){function2(item.getItemId());}

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the Sample code that I currently use in my application for Storing Data to my SDCard, have a look and try using this.

```
    File newSoundFile;
    ContentResolver mCr;

    Log.e("check this tag","path for SDCard:"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

    //storing at:  /mnt/sdcard/media 
    File directoryStructure=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Halloween");


    //if directory doesn't exist create a directory if that fails too return false
    if(!(directoryStructure.exists())){
        if(!(directoryStructure.mkdirs())){
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*for(int allRing=0;allRing<ringId.length;allRing++)*/{

        newSoundFile     = new File(directoryStructure, "/"+HalloweenWallpaper.longPressSelected+".mp3");
        Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getApplication().getPackageName()+"/"+ringId[HalloweenWallpaper.longPressSelected]);
        mCr = HalloweenWallpaper.this.getContentResolver();
        AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
        try {
            soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            soundFile=null;
            Log.e("first check", "here --"+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
            FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
            int i = fis.read(readData);

            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(readData);
            }

            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            Log.e("Second Check", "--"+io.getMessage());
            return false;
        }       

    }


    //STORES SUCCESFULLY
```